# Conditional Select after GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How should I write a conditional `Where` after a `GroupBy` to `Select` items based on a `if` statement?

I have a List of objects of type `Option`:

```
class Option {
    public Boolean Important { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I initialize my Options and a list with all of them:

```
List<Option> myOptions = new List<Option> {
    new Option { Priority = 100, Name = "Color", Value = "Red", Important = true },
    new Option { Priority = 150, Name = "Color", Value = "Blue" },
    new Option { Priority = 100, Name = "Font", Value = "16" },
    new Option { Priority = 150, Name = "Font", Value = "32"
};
```

So I have Something like:

```
///MY Options///
/// NAME --- VALUE --- PRIORITY --- IMPORTANT
/// Color -- Red ----- 100----------True
/// Color -- Blue ---- 150----------False
/// Font-----16--------100----------False
/// Font-----32--------150----------False
///
```

I need to group them by Name and take those values based on two statements:

1. Take the one with most priority having `Important` true.
2. If there's no item with `Important`, take the one with most priority.

So the goal should be:

```
    ///Color - Red  //Because has the most priority being Important
    ///Font - 32    //Because has the most priority and there's no Important
```

I'm trying to avoid multiple iterations, so I'm building a Linq query... Without success.

```
.Select(g => new {
    Name = g.Key,
     Value = g.Where(op => op.Important).OrderByDescending(op => op.Priority).First().Value
}).ToList();
```

I don't know how to resolve the `Where`. Any idea?

Comment: Quick note - your `myOptions` initialization would be *much* simpler using a collection initializer and object initializers.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, That's true. That class is just for SO to focus on the Linq

Comment: Yes, but the simpler your sample code, the easier it is to focus on the ordering part. Your 25 lines of initialization could be 6 very easily.

Comment: I've update my code in order to clarify it for future readers. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: It's still not clear why you need the variables - mind if I edit it again to just use the object initializer within the collection initializer? Less fluff that way :)

Comment: Not a problem, feel free to edit @JonSkeet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really want to *filter* by "important" but *order* by it:

```
Value = g.OrderByDescending(op => op.Important) // true first
         .ThenByDescending(op => op.Priority)
         .First()
         .Value
```